# Undelete branch in bare repository?

Tags: git

We're using Bitbucket Server which stores git repository in a "bare repository" format.

We had a developer accidentally delete a branch on the remote in a repo, is there a way to undo this?

Comment: This is for a bare repository, I don't have access to those commands I believe.

Comment: If no other dev has this repo locally, I'd ask for help BitBucket support. They should snapshot the db in worst case.

Comment: @medik AFAIU it's a local repo served with a local installation of Bitbucket Server.

Comment: Tough case then, maybe you can play around with some disk restore utils (time machine, version restore, etc.) and look through `.git/refs` until you find the branch. I don't know your OS, but it's ootb on OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

List unreferenced commits using `git fsck --unreachable`. Search for your branch using `git show` and `git log`. Create a branch using `git branch $SHA1` when you find a commit that was the head of the removed branch.